# Charging an RC circuit with two different Voltages?

Tags: remote-control

I am giving step input voltages of value 10V and 5V to an RC circuit.

Will it take equal time to charge the capacitor to its's final value?

OR

5v will take more time to charge and 10v will take less time for charging the capacitor to it's final value.

Comment: Remind yourself of the formula for "RC time constant".

Answer (score 4):

They will charge to their final value in exactly the same time. See below: -

[image]